# Problems Using glColor to set textures to half transparency

Tags: android, opengl-es

Basically I have a fully functional ogl program (2D game) in opengl es 1.1, everything works fine except for one problem: glcolor

I'm trying to set some of my texture to half transparent and I would like to do it as follows;

```
gl.glColor4f(1f, 1f, 1f, .5f);
obj.draw(gl);
...

gl.glColor4f(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f);
```

I'm using VBO for my vertice, my textures and indices. (if that is relevant)

the problem is that nothing gets set to 50% transparency...

I'm don't think relevant to post all my code (mainly because it is spread out several classes with several GL options changing (blends, scissors etc etc).

What I would like is for people to tell me what state of OGL could prevent glcolor form working like I want, what functions should I check, what state should I call.

Jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got enough time to go step by step trhough all my traces and found the problems

gl.glTexEnvf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, ...);

... was set to GL_REPLACE while generating some textures and was never set to GL_COMBINE

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled GL_BLEND?
Check out [glBlendFunc](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/1.1/docs/man/glBlendFunc.xml). I generally end up using glBlendFunc( SRC_ALPHA, ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA )

Comment: Yep GL_BLEND enabled with the right glBlendFunc. most of my textures have alpha at 0 areas so the blend already works (otherwise I would have nice big black or white squares around my textures lol)